# Laravel migration blows up on foreign key. Already using unsigned int and referencing created tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, wamp, laravel-artisan

I am racking my brain trying to figure this out, but to no avail. Please help.

I have the following code:

```
Schema::create('inventory_category_relations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('inventory_category_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->foreign('inventory_category_id')->references('id')->on('inventory_categories');
            $table->integer('inventory_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->foreign('inventory_id')->references('id')->on('inventory');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes(); 
        });
```

The above code references an 'inventory' and 'inventory_categories' table, which tables are already created and referenced by other tables, which work perfectly. However, every time I try to run "php artisan migrate" with the above code, my terminal blows up.

**Edit**
Here are my original 'inventory' and 'inventory_categories' create statements:

```
Schema::create('inventory_categories', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();
        });
Schema::create('inventory', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('basic_description');
            $table->unsignedInteger('inventory_type_id');
            $table->foreign('inventory_type_id')->references('id')->on('inventory_types')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('vendor_id');
            $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('inventory_category_id');
            $table->foreign('inventory_category_id')->references('id')->on('inventory_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->decimal('price',10,2);
            $table->decimal('compare_price',10,2);
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('sku');
            $table->string('barcode');
            $table->boolean('no_stock_purchase')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('shipping_address')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('shipping_weight')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('free_shipping')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('taxes')->default(1);
            $table->boolean('multiple_options')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('custom_variants')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
            $table->boolean('has_publish_date')->default(0);
            $table->dateTime('start_date');
            $table->dateTime('end_date');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('meta_title');
            $table->mediumText('meta_description');
            $table->boolean('has_commission')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_by');
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes(); 
        });
```

I am using laravel 4.2 on a wamp server

**Update:**
Ok I used "php artisan migrate > migrate_error.log" and posted the results to pastebin. The file was too large, but I posted what would fit:
http://pastebin.com/J8KZn7R5

Comment: What do you mean by 'my terminal blows up'. You will need to be more specific. What is the error message?

Comment: You could try to refresh the migrations using `php artisan migrate:refresh`. This will rollback all migrations and run them again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm kind of a newb, but my terminal starts outputting random laravel files lines of code until the php memory limit is hit. Also I tried doing a refresh and rollback, but still hitting the same problem.

Comment: Could you log the terminal output to a file e.g. `php artisan migrate > migrate_error.log` and then post the contents of the log file on http://pastebin.com/ for us to look at.

Comment: Firstly can you check that the indexes on the inventory an inventory_categories tables are named 'id' and are the same type (unsigned) and size as the inventory_category_id and the inventory_id fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it:**
It turns out my database configurations were wrong. My tables were configured to MyISAM, when they should have been InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there is a stack trace due to a failed SQL statement. It's saying that it can't add the foreign key constraint of inventory_category_relations.inventory_category_id to reference inventory_categories.id.

My thought would be to remove the following portion

```
->nullable()->default(null)
```

from the two column creation statements in your inventory_category_relations migration. The columns they both reference are auto-incremented primary key IDs; those should never resolve to NULL anyway.